# django session and subdomains issue

Tags: django, session-cookies

I have a page which runs in >30 subdomains as language subdomains.

I have this settings:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mysite.com"
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mysite.com"

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

but if a user logs in e.g. subdomain `de`, the `user.is_authenticated` is `False`,

what can be happening here?

I am just lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that varnish is caching lots of things which were crucial for this to work... adding except-rules to varnish solved the problem..

my advice:

be careful, if you are using multiple caching levels and keep the big picture of what is really happening in all those levels so you can figure out things if there are bugs in application level...